# asp.net core project app_data folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new at asp.net core application. I have a `settings.josn` file in `data` folder. That contains some configurations for my applicaiton. But the users should not get this file via http request (`http://10.1.15/data/settings.json`). How can I protect id. The asp.net framework applications are using app_data folder. Can I use this folder in core applciations?

Comment: By default, all static files are not available for public access except of files in `wwwroot` folder. Share your `Startup` class please.

Answer (score 0):

By default, in `Asp.Net Core` all static files are not available for public access.

If your file is accessible then just remove [the code that makes it accessible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x). Typically, such code is in `Startup` class.